# Firefox keeps failing to verify certain apps

Tags: firefox

Here's the problem.  I get a message that pops up that says, `"one or more extensions cannot be verified and have been disabled`".  I know a temporary fix to get these apps working again but the apps always break after so much time.  What I do is go in my extensions for my Firefox profile (which is a JSON file) and I use Wordpad to change all the instances of `appDisabled": true` to `appDisabled": false`.  I also change all the instances of `signedState":-1` to `signedState":2.`  The problem is that it keeps changing the false back to true and the 2's back to -1's.  I am using Firefox version **56.0.2**.  Is there any permanent fix that can keep these changes under the current version that I am using?  I am getting sick and tired of having to make these changes every day.  Also, a couple of key add-ons that I use which are Classic Theme Restorer and unblock Origin keep getting disabling from this issue.  I value these add-ons and I would love it if you knew any command prompt that I could put into Wordpad that would make Firefox stop trying to verify add-ons or whatever it does that causes Firefox to disable the add-ons.  I welcome any other fix as well.  I do want to keep my current version of Firefox and I know the Greasemonkey I use wouldn't work on later versions.

I already tried using Wordpad to change all instances o`f appDisabled": true to false` and signedState":-1 to 2.  It would work for a while and then everything reverted back to how it was.

```
...
appDisabled":true

...
signedState":-1
```

When `appDisabled is true` and `signedState switches to -1`, I get the message saying, "one or more extensions cannot be verified." It also disables the incompatible apps.

Comment: Is there anyone that can answer this question?  I've now had this question on here for five days and I'm getting sick of my apps breaking every day.

Comment: Could anyone help me with this?  I am getting sick and tired of having to keep fixing my apps.

Comment: Is there any forum on here where I can bring awareness of my question that hasn't been answered? It now has not been answered in 9 days.

Comment: Now, it's been 18 days since this has been answered and the apps keep breaking.  Could someone please answer this question?

Comment: That's it!  No one's bothering to answer my question.  It's been almost three months and no one has provided me a solution.  I'm taking this question to another coding forum.